# How to change bootstrap theme on click of link

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-themes

I want to switch between the bootstrap theme on click of link of that theme name 
here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Theme Changer</title>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <a id="Cyborg" href="" class="btn btn-block">Cyborg</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <a id="Lux" href="" class="btn btn-block">Lux</a>
        </div>
    </div>
         <footer>
            <p>Theme Changer</p>
        </footer>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Cyborg').click(function () {
        $('#theme').attr('href', 'css/bootstrapcyborg.css');
    });
    $('#Lux').click(function () {
        $('#theme').attr('href', 'css/bootstraplux.css');
    });
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have created link for initial page load css and then on click of either of the link i am replacing
original `href` attribute with i have assign in jquery. 
Can anybody suggest where i am going wrong.

Comment: I think the simple way is use variable and load css base to that variable.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini can u elaborate please

Comment: When you click on the button do you have any console error?

Comment: nope nothing there

Answer (score 0):

I can think of few solutions for that, but I would recommend first one.

1. Instead of `a` tags use `button` without `href` attribute.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <button id="Cyborg" class="btn btn-block">Cyborg</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <button id="Lux" class="btn btn-block">Lux</button>
</div>
```

2. Add `href="javascript:void(0)"` or `href="#"` to your `a` tags

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <a id="Cyborg" href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-block">Cyborg</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
   <a id="Lux" href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-block">Lux</a>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <a id="Cyborg" href="#" class="btn btn-block">Cyborg</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
   <a id="Lux" href="#" class="btn btn-block">Lux</a>
</div>
```

But keep in mind that having `'#'` as `href` will take you back to the top of the page when `a` clicked.

And also following https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a it's bad practice

> Anchor elements are often abused as fake buttons by setting their href to # or javascript:void(0) to prevent the page from refreshing, then listening for their click events .
>
> These bogus href values cause unexpected behavior when copying/dragging links, opening links in a new tab/window, bookmarking, or when JavaScript is loading, 
>   errors, or is disabled. They also convey incorrect semantics to assistive technologies, like screen readers.
>
> Use a  instead. In general, you should only use a hyperlink for navigation to a real URL.

3. Prevent firing default browser action on click

```
$('#Cyborg').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#theme').attr('href', 'css/bootstrapcyborg.css');
});
$('#Lux').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#theme').attr('href', 'css/bootstraplux.css');
});
```

4. Remove **href** atribute completely - then you might need to style `a` tags your way, because browser will remove anchor styling

Explanation:
Because `#Cyborg` or `#Lux` are anchor elements their default browser behaviour when clicked is to **initiates navigation to its URL**, because you have empty string inside `href` browser simply reloads the page. Then browser goes back to the state after first load and you see no effect.

Hope I understand you correctly and this will help